# What is the correct way of traversing the following tree pre-oder?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

Given the following parse tree:

In:

```
from nltk.parse import CoreNLPParser
from nltk.treeprettyprinter import TreePrettyPrinter

parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000')
next(parser.raw_parse('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?')).pretty_print()
```

Out:

```
                           ROOT                            
                            |                               
                          SBARQ                            
  __________________________|____________________________   
 |        SQ                                             | 
 |     ___|_________________                             |  
 |    |                     NP                           | 
 |    |        _____________|______________________      |  
 |    |       |                  PP                S     | 
 |    |       |              ____|___              |     |  
WHNP  |       NP            |        NP            VP    | 
 |    |    ___|_____        |     ___|_____        |     |  
 WP  VBZ  DT        NN      IN   DT        JJ      VB    . 
 |    |   |         |       |    |         |       |     |  
What  is the     airspeed   of   an     unladen swallow  ?
```

What is the correct way of traversing it in pre-order with and without the terminal nodes?

So far my main issue is that I dont understand how to iterate through the tree. When I do :

```
for e in parse_tree:
    print(e)
```

I get:

```
(ROOT
  (SBARQ
    (WHNP (WP What))
    (SQ
      (VBZ is)
      (NP
        (NP (DT the) (NN airspeed))
        (PP (IN of) (NP (DT an) (JJ unladen)))
        (S (VP (VB swallow)))))
    (. ?)))
```

In other words, I cant access to each branch of the tree. What is the correct way of traversing this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description **'What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'**. I think you wanted leaf node all the time if i am correct.! you should apply DFS(preorder) which will give output leaf nodes of the tree.

Code for-:**[To print leaf node]**

```
leafnodes=[]

def leafnode(node):
    if not node:
        return 
    if not node.left and not node.right:
        leafnodes.append(node.val)
    leafnode(node.left)
    leafnode(node.right)

leafnode(root)

print(leafnodes)
```